# How to add Charles Root Certificate to AppleTV simulator

Tags: apple-tv, charles-proxy

How to add Charles Root Certificate to AppleTV 15.2 simulator so you can use Charles Proxy with simulator?

Answer (score 4):

- In Charles, go to *Help -> SSL Proxying -> Save Charles Root certificate…*
- Save the certificate as `.cer` file.
- In AppleTV simulator, Go to *Settings -> Privacy* and highlight row *Share Apple TV Analytics*. Press Play/Pause on simulator remote and a button *Add Profile* will show. Select it and enter full path to the .cer file prefixed with `file://`, for example `file:///Users/bob/Downloads/charles-ssl-proxying-certificate.cer`. Then confirm trust and you are done.